# Previously instantaneous function doesn't end at second call

Tags: python

I have a weird behavior that I cannot seem to identify. I could try to summarize it up like this:

```
    def custom_function(input_list):
        output_sum = 0
        for number in input_list:
            output_sum += number
        return output_sum

    tmp_list = [0, 12, 129]
    tmp_list2 = [19, 0, 18]

    print tmp_list
    print custom_function(tmp_list)

    print tmp_list2
    print custom_function(tmp_list)
```

In this case, consider the `custom_function` to be way more complicated. I would just like to know the kind of stuff it might be coming from. If you need more insights I would love to describe `custom_function` in more details.

The output will look like this, and the script will keep running without giving any answer, while the first iteration of custom_function was instantaneous.

```
    [0, 12, 129]
    141
    [19, 0, 18]
```

Do you guys have any idea of where this kind of problem might be coming from? When I kill the script the Trace Back always indicate me a different call, as if the last function was just taking 2 days to execute.

Comment: download an IDE that has a debugger

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to answer without some actual examples. I suppose the exact code you posted works OK for you?

Comment: Are your function parameters actual lists, or are they generators?

Comment: @robertking: Your advise does not help anyone - Python is not a language dependent on IDE's - and if you knew what you were talking about, You'd give an answer suggesting the use of debugging instead

Comment: @jsbueno: StackOverflow is not a replacement for a debugger.  Besides, no programming language is "dependent" on a IDE (despite what IDE vendors will tell you).

Answer (score 1):

You have a misprint in your code. Second print operators prints tmp_list2, but to function you pass tmp_list.

So, change

```
print custom_function(tmp_list)
```

to

```
print custom_function(tmp_list2)
```

If you are going to do any manipulations (adding/deleting items) with input_list in function, try to make "for" loop over the copy of input_list [:], not the input_list itself. So your function should look like:

```
def custom_function(input_list):
    output_sum = 0
    for number in input_list[:]:
        output_sum += number
    return output_sum
```

It is not useful for your current function because there are no manipulations with contents of input_list, but you've mentioned that your real function is more complicated.